# Can I pass the result of a query as an argument to the next in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, kdb, dolphindb

I have a kdb+/q statement

```
{select from x where ...}{select from x where ...}select from table
```

Can I iteratively pass arguments like this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following script:

```
(x -> select * from x where id > 7)(select * from t where id > 5)
```

Define a lambda function `x -> select * from x where id > 7` with `select * from t where id > 5` as the passed arguments.